# TFS, is there a variable for the artifact zip file name?

Tags: artifacts

Is there a way to get the artifact file name easily? Looks like TFS already knows this as shown in the log below:

```
No path specified for search pattern: *.zip defaulting to: F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8519067Z Searching for: *.zip under directory: F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8519067Z Found: 1 files to extract:

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8519067Z F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a\ZFJ0_ServiceSearchPlusBuildDefn\BETALink.Service.SearchPlus\ZFJ0_BETALink10.4 DevOps_BETALink.Service.SearchPlus_1.0.0_886.zip

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8519067Z Creating destination folder: F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a\48

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8519067Z Extracting file: F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a\ZFJ0_ServiceSearchPlusBuildDefn\BETALink.Service.SearchPlus\ZFJ0_BETALink10.4 DevOps_BETALink.Service.SearchPlus_1.0.0_886.zip

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8519067Z [command]F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\_tasks\ExtractFiles_5e1e3830-fbfb-11e5-aab1-090c92bc4988\1.112.1\7zip\7z.exe x -oF:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a\48 F:\TFS2017_Release_Agent\_work\r1\a\ZFJ0_ServiceSearchPlusBuildDefn\BETALink.Service.SearchPlus\ZFJ0_BETALink10.4 DevOps_BETALink.Service.SearchPlus_1.0.0_886.zip

2017-12-08T16:38:36.8987827Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An artifact isn't "a file". In your specific case, it is. But in general, an artifact can contain any number of files.

There is no way to retrieve the files present in an artifact, since an artifact can also be a pointer to a UNC share.

Answer (score 1):

For others, I have to write a couple of lines to get the zip file name. ZFJ0_ServiceSearchPlusBuildDefn.DefinitionName is my {Artifact alias}:

```
$zipdir = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Release.Artifacts.ZFJ0_ServiceSearchPlusBuildDefn.DefinitionName)\$(Release.DefinitionName)"
Write-Host "zipfile directory: "$zipdir

$zipfile = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip "$zipdir"
Write-Host "zipfile : "$zipfile
```